# Java:Internal data structure in Map

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, associative-array

I am trying to create a class that implements the Map interface. So I am writing code that will check if the calling object is empty or not. However I am a little confused as to which data structure I should use internally. At present I am using a Hash Table. 
     Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array#Data_structures_for_representing),

> Associative arrays are usually used
>   when lookup is the most frequent
>   operation. For this reason,
>   implementations are usually designed
>   to allow speedy lookup, at the expense
>   of slower insertion and a larger
>   storage footprint than other data
>   structures (such as association
>   lists).
>
> **Efficient representations:**
>  There are two main efficient data
>   structures used to represent
>   associative arrays, the hash table and
>   the self-balancing binary search tree
>   (such as a red-black tree or an AVL
>   tree). Skip lists are also an
>   alternative, though relatively new and
>   not as widely used. B-trees (and
>   variants) can also be used, and are
>   commonly used when the associative
>   array is too large to reside entirely
>   in memory, for instance in a simple
>   database. Relative advantages and
>   disadvantages include:
>
> 1. Asymptotic operation performance: Hash tables have faster average lookup
>      and insertion time, O(1), compared to
>      a balanced binary search tree's Θ(log
>      n), while balanced trees have faster
>      worst-case lookup and insertion time,
>      O(log n) as compared to Θ(n). Skip
>      lists have O(n) worst-case and O(log
>      n) average-case operation times, but
>      with less insertion and deletion
>      overhead in practice than balanced
>      binary trees.
> 2. Ordering preservation: Balanced binary trees and skip lists preserve
>      ordering — allowing one to efficiently
>      iterate over the keys in order or to
>      efficiently locate an association
>      whose key is nearest to a given value.
>      Hash tables do not preserve ordering
>      and therefore cannot perform these
>      operations as efficiently (they
>      require the data to be sorted in a
>      separate step).
> 3. Range queries: Balanced binary trees can be easily adapted to
>      efficiently assign a single value to a
>      large ordered range of keys, or to
>      count the number of keys in an ordered
>      range. (With n elements in the array
>      and performing the operation on a
>      contiguous range of m keys, a balanced
>      binary tree will take O(log(n)+m) time
>      while a hash table would need Θ(n)
>      time as it needs to search the entire
>      table.)
> 4. Allocation behavior: Hash tables with open addressing store all data in
>      a large contiguous block of memory
>      that is reallocated infrequently,
>      whereas tree allocations perform many
>      small, frequent allocations. As a
>      result hash tables may be difficult to
>      allocate in a fragmented heap, and
>      conversely trees may cause heap
>      fragmentation. Trees are also more
>      vulnerable to inefficiencies in
>      allocators.
> 5. Compactness: Hash tables can have more compact storage for small value
>      types, especially when the values are
>      bits.
> 6. Persistence: There are simple persistent versions of balanced binary
>      trees, which are especially prominent
>      in functional languages.
> 7. Supporting new key types: Building a hash table requires a reasonable
>      hash function for the key type, which
>      can be difficult to write well, while
>      balanced binary trees and skip lists
>      only require a total ordering on the
>      keys.
>
> Sometimes simple implementations of
>   one data structure or the other have
>   disadvantages that can be overcome by
>   better design. For example:
>
> - Hash tables that use untrusted input as keys may be vulnerable to
>     denial-of-service attacks where an
>     untrusted user supplies data intended
>     to generate large numbers of
>     collisions. This may be overcome by
>     choosing hash functions at random from
>     a universal family, or by hashing
>     untrusted input with a cryptographic
>     hash function before insertion.
> - Simple balanced trees waste space on    pointers and allocation
>     metadata;    these problems can be
>     mitigated by    storing multiple
>     elements in each    node and by using
>     memory pools.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the table itself you could also maintain an integer member variable to track the size of the collection, incrementing it each time a new mapping is put and decrementing each time one is removed.  This way, you can simplify the `size` and `isEmpty` interface methods:

```
public int size() {
    return this.size;
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return this.size == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried different methods but ended up extending some data structure that was itself so strong that no coding skills were needed for it. So I decided to use normal string arrays( 2) to from a virtual hash map like structure which would expand as the need for space increased.

Below is the link to the complete code.

http://code.google.com/p/rohan-oopconcept-assignment/source/browse/trunk/src/EmployeeMap.java